# Save specified string into MySQL database from all files in directory

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've found different solutions on "crawling" sites but they don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

I'd like the ability to extract data from each file in an online directory and save the results into a MySQL database:

```
http://www.website.com/directory/subdirectory/
```

This subdirectory contains several different sub-subdirectories that contain the information I'm looking for.

These sub-subdirectories contain the following elements with the data I'd like to store:

```
<h1 class="title">Title</h1>
<h2 class="details">Details</h2>
```

Then, 2 paragraph tags with additional data:

```
<p>Text</p>
<p>More Text</p>
```

Lastly:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Text</p>
```

Ideally, I'd like to store each bit of text into the database, something like:

```
$title = //all text between <h1> and </h1>;
$details = //all text between <h2> and </h2>;
$detailText1 = //all text between the FIRST set of <p> and </p>
$detailText2 = //all text between the SECOND set of <p> and </p>
$title2 = //all text between <h3> and </h3>;
$title2Text = //all text between the THIRD set of <p> and </p>;

mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (id, title, details, detailText1, detailText2, title2, title2Text) VALUES (NULL, "'.$title.'", "'.$details.'", "'.detailText1.'", "'.$detailText2.'", "'.$title2.'")');
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get h1,h2,.....and any tag's.
For example:

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.wikipedia.org');
// Find all h1
foreach($html->find('h1') as $element) 
       echo $element->outertext. '<br/>';
```

Comment: Hey yones, thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried to implement but receive: "[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"

Comment: This is not a problem with your script, but with the resource you are requesting. The web server is returning the "forbidden" status code.It could be that it blocks PHP scripts to prevent scraping, or your IP if you have made too many requests.
You should probably talk to the administrator of the remote server.